# Magento - how to issue a refund programmatically?

Tags: magento

How can an order be refunded in Magento programmatically? To be more precise, how can an order that is in pending state and status be changed to appropriate refund state and/or status.

Comment: Are looking to issue a credit memo offline or is your goal to trigger an online refund via the payment gateway?

Comment: I'm trying to process a refund ipn from a gateway on Magento side (change status to apropriate one, issue memo, whatever the proper process is). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't do this via the IPN facility as the gateways are notifying *Magento* of an action that has already happened. If you want to actually refund online it requires little more than extending or calling the saveAction of CreditmemoController.

This is the controller action that actually does the refunding but relies on protected methods within the controller. To use this you would post directly to it - for instance post to `https://yoursite.com/admin/sales/order/creditmemo/save/` or in a pinch you could duplicate the methods into one monolithic script.

```
<?php 

//taken from /app/code/core/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreditmemoController.php


    /**
     * Save creditmemo
     * We can save only new creditmemo. Existing creditmemos are not editable
     */
    public function saveAction()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('creditmemo');
        if (!empty($data['comment_text'])) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setCommentText($data['comment_text']);
        }

        try {
            $creditmemo = $this->_initCreditmemo();
            if ($creditmemo) {
                if (($creditmemo->getGrandTotal() <=0) && (!$creditmemo->getAllowZeroGrandTotal())) {
                    Mage::throwException(
                        $this->__('Credit memo\'s total must be positive.')
                    );
                }

                $comment = '';
                if (!empty($data['comment_text'])) {
                    $creditmemo->addComment(
                        $data['comment_text'],
                        isset($data['comment_customer_notify']),
                        isset($data['is_visible_on_front'])
                    );
                    if (isset($data['comment_customer_notify'])) {
                        $comment = $data['comment_text'];
                    }
                }

                if (isset($data['do_refund'])) {
                    $creditmemo->setRefundRequested(true);
                }
                if (isset($data['do_offline'])) {
                    $creditmemo->setOfflineRequested((bool)(int)$data['do_offline']);
                }

                $creditmemo->register();
                if (!empty($data['send_email'])) {
                    $creditmemo->setEmailSent(true);
                }

                $creditmemo->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(!empty($data['send_email']));
                $this->_saveCreditmemo($creditmemo);
                $creditmemo->sendEmail(!empty($data['send_email']), $comment);
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('The credit memo has been created.'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getCommentText(true);
                $this->_redirect('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $creditmemo->getOrderId()));
                return;
            } else {
                $this->_forward('noRoute');
                return;
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot save the credit memo.'));
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/new', array('_current' => true));
    }
```

HTH, Cheers.